# (AJAX JSON) How to get body response in Browser URL?

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

Is there anyway to get body response of AJAX by enter directly to URL from Browser?
I know, if I want to get body response of this content, I just need to input  >> **javascript:file_download()** to Browser URL.

**My question is** *Is there anyway to get body response in Browser like this way?*

```
http://onecloud.media/file/Y05SMFlGZ205WjgzNjk?type=file_download&xx=zz&xx=zz&blah=blah
```

.

.

> Target: http://onecloud.media/file/Y05SMFlGZ205WjgzNjk

```
    file_download = function() {
    var a = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr("content");
    return !a || $click ? !1 : ($click = 1, $("#response").html('<i class="fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin fa-2x fa-fw pull-left"></i>'), $datas = "", $datas += "type=file_download", void $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "",
        headers: {
            "X-CSRF-TOKEN": a
        },
        dataType: "json",
        data: $datas,
        success: function(a) {
            if (a.status) window.location.replace(a.msg);
            else {
                $(".msg-danger").show(), $(".msg-danger span").html(a.msg);
                var e = setInterval(function() {
                    clearInterval(e), $(".msg-danger span").html(""), $(".msg-danger").hide()
                }, 3e3)
            }
            $("#response").html('<i class="fa fa-cloud-download fa-2x pull-left"></i>'), $click = 0
        },
        error: function(a) {
            $click = 0, $(".msg-danger").show(), $(".msg-danger span").html("Có lỗi xảy ra, vui lòng thử lại");
            var e = setInterval(function() {
                clearInterval(e), $(".msg-danger span").html(""), $(".msg-danger").hide()
            }, 3e3);
            console.log("Request: " + a.status + "\nStatus: " + a.statusText), $("#response").html('<i class="fa fa-cloud-download fa-2x pull-left"></i>')
        }
    }))
},
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. What does "get body response" mean?

Comment: I means the file when I click download

Comment: I don't think it's possible to capture a download.

Comment: What about json code? Can I get json code, that contains the download link?

Comment: I take it back. Usually a file download is done by opening a separate window that goes to a URL that sends the file as an attachment. I think if you access that URL with AJAX you should be able to get the file contents. But that will only work if the server is in the same domain or it allows cross-domain AJAX.

Comment: Please give an example for the Target. 
When I try to enter `http://onecloud.media/file/Y05SMFlGZ205WjgzNjk?type=file_download`. Browser return error, I can't see URL in json code

Comment: That link doesn't download the file, it just goes to a page that has buttons you have to click on to start a download. Those buttons probably execute Javascript to start the download.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. Actually I just want to know how its can redirect to `https://r1---sn-oguesnze.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?......`